# How to append an optional UIImage to an array

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIViewController with 2 `UITextFields` and 1 `UIImageView` (the image is optional)
When I click `Save` I want to save all values in an array of objects. But the image (`selectedImage`) is not mandatory.
The issue is with the `UIImage` because is asking me for an `optional` value for the `UIImage` if I don't have an image. And I don't know what to assign because I don't want to have any image in my array if the user did't picked a picture. And I've tried to put a NIL value but is not working.

Here is my code for Model:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class RoadsideDefect {

    var vehicleReg: String
    var detailsDefect: String
    var imagesDefect: [UIImage]?

    init(vehicleRegistration: String, detailsOfDefect: String, imagesOfDefects: [UIImage]?) {

        self.vehicleReg = vehicleRegistration
        self.detailsDefect = detailsOfDefect
        self.imagesDefect = imagesOfDefects
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the Controller:

```
var vehicleReg = ""
var detailsDefect = ""
var imagesDefect: [UIImage]? = [UIImage]()
var roadsideDefect: [RoadsideDefect] = []

//MARK: Save button tapped

@IBAction func saveBtnTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    guard let vehicleRegText = vehicleRegTextfieldOutlet.text, !vehicleRegText.isBlank else {
        showAlertWithTitle(title: "Error", message: "Please add vehicle reg number.")
        return
    }

    guard let detailsText = detailsTextfieldOutlet.text, !detailsText.isBlank else {
        showAlertWithTitle(title:  "Error", message: "Please add some details.")
        return
    }

    let selectedImage: UIImage? = roadsideDefectImageView?.image

    vehicleReg = vehicleRegText
    detailsDefect = detailsText

// ISSUE HERE
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(selectedImage ?? HowToSetItNilOrEmpty?, self, #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil) 

    roadsideDefect.append(RoadsideDefect(vehicleRegistration: vehicleReg, detailsOfDefect: detailsDefect, imagesOfDefects: imagesDefect))


print(roadsideDefect)
}
```

I marked the issue with a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if let image = selectedImage {
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}
```

Comment: This was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional binding for unwrapping optionals.

```
guard let imageView = roadsideDefectImageView else { return }
guard let image = imageView.image else { return }
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

Comment: I will don't get the warnings for empty fields if I use this way. Because that return will stop the execution of the block of code in my function.

Comment: You can call your specific alert function instead of `return`.